# Изменение данных ячейки в датафрэйм пандас

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Я построил датафрэйм из 48 файлов в формате .s2p, но она функционалы такой же как csv. И я добавил для каждой строке соответствующую имя файла. Но в столбце написано полный путь к файлу например: 'C:\Users\77081\Desktop\Новая папка\Cu_15_C5-1_4,6_multibias_spar_0.000_8.000.s2p'
Все имена файлов идентичны кроме '0.000_8.000'. И мне нужно так чтобы в столбце были лишь эти цифры.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r'C:\Users\77081\Desktop\Новая папка' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.s2p")
new_list = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+', skiprows= 3, header=None)
    df['filename']= filename
    new_list.append(df)
dataset = pd.concat(new_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: пользуйтесь библиотекой pathlib для обработки имен файлов .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если все имена файлов идентичны, то можно обойтись простым срезом. Попробуйте заменить `df['filename'] = filename` на это:

```
df['filename'] = filename[-15:-4]
```

Comment: а что, по-вашему, должен делать ваш код? присваивать всей колонке датафрейма с именем 'filname' строку со срезом?

Comment: Точно. Сейчас там у автора вопроса полный путь к файлу, а он хочет его сократить.

Comment: Значит имена файлов у вас все же не идентичны. Вы не привели никаких данных, поэтому трудно предложить рабочий вариант. Видимо без регулярных выражений тут не обойтись.

Comment: dataset['Vgs'] = dataset['Vgs'].str.replace('_', '') Получилось спасибо большое.